# Save <iframe> contents to variable in jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I need to save the content of the following code:

```
"<iframe src = 'info / info_template'> </ iframe>";
```

What I want, in jQuery, is to take the html that is in "src = info / info_template" and save it in a variable, either in HTML or in text, I do not care.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: What do you intend to do with it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of `src` using jQuery's `.attr()` method. 
[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/e35k2tov/7/)

```js
// Storing the src as a variable here.
var iframeSrc = $('iframe').attr('src');

//adding the above variable to "append-here" here
$('#append-here').text(iframeSrc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com">
</iframe>
<div id="append-here">
</div>
```